# How to find a td of a table in div to set text in td from checkboxes which is in another nested div ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a td in a table. There are multiple rows of data coming from database and every row has a unique id. When i click on the td a dialog box opens which have multiple checkboxes. When i select these values of checkboxex and hit submit these are to be shown in td without page refresh. What i am trying to do is find that td and set the text to it on submit. But my page contains lots of functionality and there are lots of div in it, it is very hard to find its location via finding parent child etc. Is there any way so that i can directly find that td with its unique id of row. Below is my code:

```
<div></div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="autoval">
    <div>
      <div>
     </div>
     <div>
         <div>
         <table>
            <tr id="123unique">
                <td></td><td></td><td "to set text"></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="768unique">
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="ui-dialog">
<div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" checked="" value="Adam">
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" checked="" value="Eve">
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" checked="" value="Ana">
</div>
<input type="button" name="checked_submit" id="checked_submit" value="submit">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share code to open dialog box and submit it. share jsfiddle link if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('td').click(function(){
  var parent =  $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the parent id when `td` clicked

```
$('td').click(function(){
  var idOfTheParentElement =  $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save the parent before opening the dialog and then onclose do something with that parent:

```
$("td").click(function() {

    var parent = $(this).parent();

    // dialog code here
    $.dialogOrSomething({
        onClose: function() {
            doSomethingWithParent(parent);
        }
    })

});
```